# A misunderstanding with Faraday's experiment with iron ring

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, electromagnetic, induction, emf

I am learning about electricity and magnetism, and have got some misunderstanding about Faraday's experiments with iron ring.

If iron can conduct electricity, why is electricity inducted only while the switch is on? Why can't electricity flow through the iron ring to the other coil while the circuit is looped?

[image]

Comment: The wire is electrically insulated from the iron ring. This is all about magnetics.

Comment: It induces the magnetic field, not conduct electricity by conduction. Magnetic wire is a thin insulation coating usually light brown wrapped over thin Teflon or PLastic  tape.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 so, it means that coils have insulation coating?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_wire

Answer (score 0):

The electricity flowing in the left hand circuit induces a magnetic field which is concentrated by the iron ring.

As the switch is opened the collapsing magnetic field causes a current to flow in the right hand circuit.

Comment: I understand electromagnetic induction theory, but I wonder why iron can't conduct electricity since coils are connected to the same iron ring

Comment: Well, the wire wrapped around the ring is insulated, either by plastic or even a coat of varnish can be sufficient.

Comment: thanks for explanation